# iOS returning incorrect GMT time

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I have a method to return the GMT time in iOS. It works fine on most instances and returns a string like `2016-03-23T17:13:22Z`. However, we have noticed in production that for some users the date string returned is invalid. For example, `2016-03-24T1:02:44 PMZ` or `2016-03-23T7:45:16 PMZ`. What does the `PMZ` stand for here? We have tried to reproduce the issue by changing the Phone region, calendar etc in the settings but could not.

Here is the method I use to generate the GMT time

```
+ (NSString *)gmtTimeString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? Matt pointed out that it seems to be a duplicate and setting the locale could be a fix? But, could someone please let me know what device settings could cause this bug so I can verify the fix later?

Comment: FYI - do not quote the `Z` in the date format. That's the timezone specification. Let the date formatter parse the timezone specified in the string. This also means there is no reason to set the timezone on the date formatter. Also, there is no need to quote the punctuation in the date format, just the `T`. So you want: `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll update my code with the correct format. I updated my phone to 12-hour time but still it returned me the 24-formatted string so wondering where the `PMZ` string comes from.

Comment: That's covered in the duplicate question.

Comment: Ok i'll check that out. Thanks again!